# How to get request with JSESSIONID c#?

Tags: c#, jsessionid

I've a problem with a C# HTTP GET request. 
I send two requests to server:
The first request returns the value of JSESSIONID and it's work:

```
private string GetSessionId(){
{
    string id = null;
    try
    {
        var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.it/home") as HttpWebRequest;
        var response = "";

        webRequest.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.5");
        webRequest.Connection = "keep-alive";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        webRequest.Host = "www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.it";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36";

        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            using (WebResponse resp = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                    {
                        id = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
                        response = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine("Response1> " + resp.Headers);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    return id;
}
```

The second request should return the server response to my search but it return an error "302 Moved Temporarily" or "Attention the session has expired".

```
private void RequestFromServer(string url)
{
    string session = GetSessionId().Split(';')[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Session> {0}",session);

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        var response = "";

        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            Uri target = new Uri(url);
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
            webRequest.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
            webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.5");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            webRequest.Connection = "keep-alive";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", session);
            webRequest.Host = "www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.it";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Origin", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.it");
            webRequest.Referer = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.it/ricerca/atto/contratti/originario?reset=true&normativi=false";
            webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

            var res = webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (Stream s = res.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                {
                    response = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(res.Headers);
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need here is a [CookieContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx). Instead of

```
webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", session);
```

you should do something like

```
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
Cookie cookie = new new Cookie("JSESSIONID", yourSessionIdHere);
// adjust domain accordingly
cookie.Domain = "www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.it";
httpRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
```

Code is untested.

The MSDN site also states:

> For security reasons, cookies are disabled by default. If you want to use cookies, use the CookieContainer property to enable cookies.

That means in order to use cookies you have to set the CookieContainer explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this code returns an exception that I solved: webRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("JSESSIONID", yourSessionIdHere){ Domain = "www.xxxxxxxxxxx.it" });  but this don't resolve my problem.

Comment: I have edited my answer. According to the error message (if my translation is correct), one needs to set the domain for the cookie, too. See [Cookie documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie(v=vs.110).aspx) for more properties of the Cookie class.

Comment: Yes, I added the domain but my problem is not solved.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Is there another exception or error message? If so, please post it.

Comment: The problem is always that the second request should return the server response to my search but it return "Attention the session has expired".